# Finding the transform of a function with a picture of the graph?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

How can we find the transform of a function just given its graph?  I know the definition implies some type of differentiation (which should be easily obtained from the graph), but I'm still having trouble making the connection.

For example, suppose we had this graph.  Is finding an explicit transform possible?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to compute the Laplace transform (which you didn't state other than in the tags), you only have to calculate the integral

$$\mathcal{L} \left\{f(t)\right\}(s)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-st} f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t.$$

which in your example seems to be the immediate integral

$$\mathcal{L} \left\{f(t)\right\}(s)=\int_{3}^{5} 2e^{-st} \,\mathrm{d}t.$$